# Struggling with Promise.race() implementation

Tags: javascript, promise

I saw following implementation of Promise.race().

I am finding it difficult of understand, how it's working.

```
const race = function(promisesArray) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    promisesArray.forEach((innerPromise) => {
      Promise.resolve(innerPromise)
        .then(resolve, reject) 
        .catch(reject);
    });
  });
};
```

1st part: Is the below statement true?

Promise.resolve(innerPromise) will always return a resolved promise with innerPromise as value and as it always resolves, I will always end up in .then block.

2nd Part:

I read in the explanation that resolve and reject passed to .then block will be called on resolution of innerPromise. Why?, shouldn't it be as Promise.resolve(innerPromise) always resolve, always 1st callback of .then block should get called?

I think I am missing something very basic. I have tried to find the solution but not able to find an explanation that clears my doubts.

Comment: I’m not sure what the `.catch(reject)` is for. That looks like a mistake, unless it’s trying to support alternative (bad) implementations of the `Promise` interface.

Comment: @Ry- yeah, I don't think it's possible. It'd technically catch errors from `resolve` or `reject` but there cannot really be errors coming from calling `resolve` or `reject`, as these are the executor function parameters. So, unless the promise constructor gives faulty `resolve`/`reject` or the `.then()` somehow ignores the second argument (both of which are non-standard for promises) I don't see how the `.catch` would ever be meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.resolve(anotherPromise)` will *always* assume the state of `anotherPromise`, so if it `anotherPromise` is rejected, then the one from `Promise.resolve()` will also be rejected. Or if `anotherPromise` is fulfilled, the `Promise.resolve()` one will also be fulfilled with its value.

```js
const rejectedPromise = Promise.reject("boom");

Promise.resolve(rejectedPromise)
  .then(result => console.log("success:", result))
  .catch(error => console.log("failure:", error));
```

See [the documentation on MDN for `Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve).

As for *why* the code is using `Promise.resolve()` instead of directly

```
innerPromise
    .then(resolve, reject) 
    .catch(reject);
```

`Promise.resolve()` is useful when the input is not necessarily a promise. It can convert a plain value to a promise or an arbitrary thenable (potentially another promise implementation) to a vanilla JavaScript promise thus allowing for uniform way of handling the result.

Perhaps this is defensive coding or just allows for calling `race(asyncResult, 42)`. The intention is not clear.

---

The `resolve` or `reject` parameters of into the executor function are noop when repeatedly called. A promise can reach a single final state - calling `resolve`/`reject` after that has no effect. Thus from the whole array, the first promise which leaves the pending state will determine what the promise constructor will be resolved as.

```js
const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Promise.resolve("p1 success")
      .then(resolve, reject) 
      .catch(reject);
  Promise.reject("p1 failure")
      .then(resolve, reject) 
      .catch(reject);
});

const p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Promise.reject("p2 failure")
      .then(resolve, reject) 
      .catch(reject);
  Promise.resolve("p2 success")
      .then(resolve, reject) 
      .catch(reject);
});

const p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Promise.resolve("p3 hello")
      .then(resolve, reject) 
      .catch(reject);
  Promise.resolve("p3 world")
      .then(resolve, reject) 
      .catch(reject);
});

const p4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Promise.reject("p4 foo")
      .then(resolve, reject) 
      .catch(reject);
  Promise.reject("p4 bar")
      .then(resolve, reject) 
      .catch(reject);
});

p1.then(console.log, console.error);
p2.then(console.log, console.error);
p3.then(console.log, console.error);
p4.then(console.log, console.error);
```

Therefore, by looping and attaching the same `resolve` and `reject` to all promises, `race` will only resolve with the same outcome of the first promise to resolve. This matches the JavaScript implementation of [`Promise.race()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race):

> ### Return value
>
> A Promise that **asynchronously settles** with the eventual state of the first promise in the `iterable` to settle. In other words, it fulfills if the first promise to settle is fulfilled, and rejects if the first promise to settle is rejected. The returned promise remains pending forever if the `iterable` passed is empty. If the `iterable` passed is non-empty but contains no pending promises, the returned promise is still asynchronously (instead of synchronously) settled.

N.B. `iterable` is the input to `Promise.race()`. It matches `promisesArray` of `race()`.

---

With all that said, the following construct seems entirely superfluous:

```
p
  .then(resolve, reject) 
  .catch(reject);
```

[The second parameter to `.then()` is the onRejected callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#parameters). So if `p` is rejected, the second argument to `.then()` would be used to handle that. The extra `.catch()` would handle errors coming from either `resolve` or `reject` in the `.then()`

```js
Promise.resolve("foo")
  .then(
    result => { throw `Fulfilled with ${result}. Throwing after success.` }, 
    error => {throw `Fulfilled with ${error}. Throwing after error` }
  )
  .catch(errorFromThen => console.log(`Error in .catch() is: ${errorFromThen}`));

Promise.reject("bar")
  .then(
    result => { throw `Fulfilled with ${result}. Throwing after success.` }, 
    error => {throw `Fulfilled with ${error}. Throwing after error` }
  )
  .catch(errorFromThen => console.log(`Error in .catch() is: ${errorFromThen}`));
```

Yet, neither `resolve` nor `reject` from the executor function can throw/reject in a plain Promise constructor.

```js
//more verbose onError and .catch() handlers in order to showcase what gts shown or not
const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Promise.reject("hello")
    .then(
      resolve, 
      error => {
        console.log("inside the onReject in .then()", error);
        return reject(error);
      })
    .catch(error => {
          console.log("inside the .catch()", error);
          return reject(error);
      });
    
    Promise.reject("world")
      .then(
        resolve, 
        error => {
          console.log("inside the onReject in .then()", error);
          return reject(error);
        }
      )
      .catch(error => {
          console.log("inside the .catch()", error);
          return reject(error);
      });
});

p.then(console.log, console.error);
```

The extra `.catch()` is thus not used.

---

Overall, `race()` behaves like the vanilla JavaScript `Promise.race()`. The only major difference is that `Promise.race()` accepts any iterable, while `race()` only handles arrays.

```js
const delay = (ms, value) =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, value));

const array = [delay(300, "a"), delay(100, "b"), delay(200, "c")];
const iterable = array.values();

Promise.race(iterable)
  .then(result => console.log(`First to fulfil was ${result}`));
```

```js
const race = function(promisesArray) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    promisesArray.forEach((innerPromise) => {
      Promise.resolve(innerPromise)
        .then(resolve, reject) 
        .catch(reject);
    });
  });
};

const delay = (ms, value) =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, value));

const array = [delay(300, "a"), delay(100, "b"), delay(200, "c")];
const iterable = array.values();

race(iterable)
  .then(result => console.log(`First to fulfil was ${result}`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of `Promise.resolve` in that code is to allow elements of the array to *not* be promises. They could be arbitrary thenables, or they could just be regular values (which will indeed become fulfilled promises).

```js
const existingValue = 5;
const existingPromise = Promise.reject(new Error("blah"));
const existingThenable = {
    then() {
        console.log("never going to resolve >:)");
    }
};

Promise.race([existingValue, existingPromise, existingThenable]).then(
    value => { console.log("got a value", value); },
    error => { console.log("got an error", error); },
);
```

> 1st part: Is the below statement true?
>
> Promise.resolve(innerPromise) will always return a resolved promise with innerPromise as value and as it always resolves, I will always end up in .then block.

If you try removing `existingValue` from the array passed to `Promise.race` above, you’ll see that `Promise.resolve` doesn’t necessarily return a resolved promise; specifically, when it’s passed a promise or other thenable, it returns a promise that settles the same way (although when passed the same type of promise, it actually satisfies that obligation by returning the same promise object). So no, it’s not true. I think that answers part 2, too.

Additionally, although you didn’t bring it up: I’m pretty sure the additional `.catch(reject)` is unreachable/useless, at least for the standard ES `Promise` implementation.

Comment: Okay so what I am getting from this is 
Promise.resolve(innerPromise) method creates a new promise that is pending until the input promise is settled. If the input promise is resolved, the new promise will also be resolved with the same value. If the input promise is rejected, the new promise will also be rejected with the same reason, right?